# Bootstrap tags input not working using document ready

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have this function for the [bootstrap tags input](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: function (query) {
                return $.getJSON('citynames.json');
            }
        }
    })
});
```

But this plugin does not work. I think it has a conflict with jQuery `(document).ready`. How can I fix this?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5sgs3/2/) (for better understanding code)

Comment: one thing to note, your live demo isn't going to work due to the service not allowing the request. There are a few errors occurring in the console.

Comment: Yes, i add this live demo for Better understanding.

Comment: If you remove `data-role="tagsinput"`, it appears to somewhat get farther than with it. Likely because with it bootstrap will automatically initialize it, and without it you can manually initialize it the way you were trying to.

Comment: worked for me! remove attribute from tag and do it with $('#tags').tagsinput();

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: function (query, process) {
                process($.getJSON('citynames.json'));
            }
        }
    })
});
```